# How to get URL from Safari browser

Tags: c#, browser, safari

How can I access the Safari browser from C# to get the current URL?

Comment: You want to launch Safari, or the default browser?

Comment: Not being a Safari user, I'm not sure if it allows multiple windows or not, but if it does, how will you decide which one you want to get the URL from, assuming that the active tab is the one you want to treat as 'current'.

Answer (score 0):

It's not exactly the best answer, but I've accomplished this by bringing focus to the safari window, and then using SendKeys to send a "Ctrl + l" which selects the URL Bar, "Ctrl + C" which copys the contents to the clipboard.  Then grab the contents of the clipboard and save it to a string, or you can save it to a list of strings, and bring focus back to the window, "Ctrl + Tab" , Repeat above process.  This would of course require that you allow the program to do its job, and you may also want to put a slight delay in between iterations of that loop.  SendKeys is not a good solution, but it does work if you allow for sufficient delay and provision for activating focus on each iteration of the loop.  Other than that, there may be a sessions file that can be parsed using regular expressions