# How can we get the current tab url of safari browser in c#?

Tags: c#, safari

I tried it many ways to retrieve the current tab url of safari browser but still unsuccessfull,i am able to retrieve url from IE,mozilla and google chrome browser,the safari browser uses webkitedit.,is there any solution to this browser to get its url

Comment: Do you try this with adapting hAddressBox ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041141/getting-active-tab-url-from-safari

Comment: i have tried every code i have found and also the link which you have shared,but it is not retrieving the url,its not returning any value,its just returning null.

Comment: Or if you can use a dirty solution : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3482750/how-to-get-url-from-safari-browser?rq=1

Comment: its not the way i wanted.